# How Do I Log USB Modem AT Command Output?

Tags: bash, usb-modem, logging

I want to be able to send the command "AT+CSQ" to /dev/ttyUSB1 every 5 seconds, and log out response to a text file. I can do it manually via screen (screen /dev/ttyUSB1 and type in AT+CSQ and see the response), but how do I do this as a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example script with some logic for logging and cleanup when the script terminates (the `trap` command). Important trick is to keep the input from the serial port open otherwise the input from the time the port was closed could get lost.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/var/tmp/modemlog
MODEM=/dev/ttyUSB1
MODEMCMD=AT+CSQ
INTERVAL=5

LOGDATE="date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"

# write command to modem
wrmodem () {
    echo -ne "$*"'\r\n' >"$MODEM"
    log "--- sent: $*"
}

# log message to a logfile
log () {
    echo "$($LOGDATE) $@" >>"$LOGFILE"
}

# logger
{
    trap 'log "=== logger stopped $BASHPID"' EXIT
    log "=== logger started: $BASHPID"
    while true ; do
        if read ; then
            log "$(tr -d \\r <<<"$REPLY")"
        fi
    done
} <"$MODEM" &

LOGGERPID=$!
trap 'kill $LOGGERPID' EXIT

# requester
while true ; do
    wrmodem "$MODEMCMD"
    sleep $INTERVAL
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `expect` tool is designed for just this sort of task. `man expect` will get you started.